# Order of $(F_{k-1}$ mod $p)$ in $F_p^*$ for primefactor $p$ of fermat number $F_k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a primefactor of $F_k = 2^{2^k} + 1$. 
I proved that $(2$ mod $ p)$ has order $2^{k+1}$ in $F_p^*$.
Suppose that $k \geq 2$. How does it follow that $(F_{k-1}$ mod $p)$ has order $2^{k+2}$ in $F_p^*$ ?
I tried squaring $(F_{k-1}$ mod $p )$ but I couldn't show it was equal to $(2 $ mod $p)$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I made a mistake
$$F_{k-1}^2\equiv F_{k-1}^2-F_k=2^{2^{k-1}+1}\pmod{p}.$$
In other words $F_{k-1}^2$ is congruent to an **odd** power of two modulo $p$.
If you know that the order of $2$ is a power of two, what can you say about the order of its odd powers?

---

Hint: In any group we have the rule that if $\operatorname{ord}(g)=n$, then
$$
\operatorname{ord}(g^m)=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,m)}.
$$

---

Just in case you simply want to show that $2^{k+2}\mid (p-1)$ there is another route. You already know that $p\equiv1\pmod8$. Therefore the law of quadratic reciprocity tells you that $2$ is a square in $F_p^*$.

Comment: I'm sorry, all the two's are confusing me. Could you explain your comment about the order of odd powers of 2?